# Import & Read excel file with Statrtswith any specific string("TRUE")

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am trying import & read Excel file which start with name "TRUE".
but actually it complete name is TRUE_management.xlsx

```
import os
import pandas as pd
files=os.listdir(r'C:\')
for f in files:
    if f.startswith("TRUE"):
        MDB=pd.read_excel("TRUE")
```

Comment: Change `pd.read_excel("TRUE")` to `pd.read_excel(f)`?

Comment: thanks , yes it working...i want to discard first row...is it possible to captures that syntax in same line of code?

Comment: You mean the very first line of all the excel files? Try using `pd.read_excel(f, skiprows=[0])`

Comment: yes very first line, but when i aplying skiprows, then trying to remove index (index=False), idex not getting removed(from column)

Answer (score 0):

pass filename in read_excel

```
import os
import pandas as pd
files=os.listdir(r'C:\')
for f in files:
    if f.startswith("TRUE"):
        MDB=pd.read_excel(f)
```